# Jquery regex in a div's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, optimization

I'd like to know how can I apply a regular expression to replace something inside a `div`.

Example:

```
<div class="counter">
  Number of viewers: 12
</div>
```

I want to replace `12` with `13`. I usually do

```
$var = $('.counter').text().replace(/\d+/g, '13');
$('.counter').text($var);
```

But I find this solution gross and unoptimized, I want an one line solution in order for `Javascript/Jquery` not to keep in memory a variable which may contains ten thousand characters.

Comment: I don't think you got many options. `replace` will already make a copy . You can just write it in one line if you want `$('.counter').text($('.counter').text().replace(/\d+/g, '13'));` to get rid of `$var`

Comment: I already thought of it, but I found it ugly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one-liner will still suffer from the same problem: a string with 10,000 characters will be needlessly created.

The real problem is your HTML. Structure it better:

```
<div class="counter">
    Number of viewers: <span id="num-viewers">12</span>
</div>
```

You can now update the number directly:

```
$('#num-viewers').text('13');
```

Comment: this is what i would have answered too!